# array_unique() without sorting

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I'm building an autoloader that extends the include_path.  It takes an array, appends the explode()d include path, removes all references to the current directory, adds a single current directory at the start of the array, and finally join() the whole thing back together to form a new include path.  The code is listed below

```
<?php
static public function extendIncludePath (array $paths)
{
    // Build a list of the current and new paths
    $pathList   = array_merge (explode (PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths), explode (PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path ()));
    // Remove any references to the current directory from the path list
    while ($key = array_search ('.', $pathList))
    {
        unset ($pathList [$key]);
    }
    // Put a current directory reference to the front of the path
    array_unshift ($pathList, '.');
    // Generate the new path list
    $newPath    = implode (PATH_SEPARATOR, $pathList);
    if ($oldPath = set_include_path ($newPath))
    {
        self::$oldPaths []  = $oldPath;
    }
    return ($oldPath);
}
?>
```

I wanted to also use array_unique() on the array before imploding it so that PHP doesn't keep looking in the same place multiple times if someone is careless and specifies the same path more than once.  However, I also need to maintain the sort order of the array because include looks in the directories in the order they're defined in the include path.  I want to look in the current directory first, then my list of search directories and finally the original include path so that, for example, an old version of a common library in the default include_path doesn't get included in favour of a newer version in my search list.

For these reasons I can't use array_unique() because it sorts the array's contents.

Is there a way of getting array_unique to preserve the order of the elements in my array?

Comment: Sort of bypassing your enquiry: Is `$array = array_flip(array_flip($array))` an option for you? (`array_flip` swaps values with keys, and since keys are always unique, a double `array_flip` makes the values in your array unique.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not using array_unique() directly; but array_unique does preserve the keys, so you can do a ksort() afterwards to recreate the original order of entries

Answer (score 5):

you may also use array_count_value. you will get your unique array result at key of your function result

its doesn't break your array sort content.

reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Ooh, creative approach! Quickref for the curious: `$unique = array_keys(array_count_values($source));`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$temp = array();

foreach ( $original_array as $value ) {
    $temp[$value] = 1;
}

$original_array = array_keys($temp);
```

Comment: Heads-up: There's a function for that loop [effectively; if you don't care for the value being `1`]. `array_flip()`. :)

Comment: Oh damn I fell to PHP rule #0: there's always a PHP function you never heard of :)

Comment: Bahaha. :D * sings a song to the PHP functions that lurk in wait to ambush the unsuspecting, praying for safe passage! *